# How to use in clause in @ManyToMany relationship in @Query annotation in spring boot jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using manytomany relationship entity in JPA IN clause but query is throwing exception. How to pass the entity to correct the JPA Query

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_master")
public class UserMaster {
    public UserMaster() {}
    public UserMaster(String userName) {
        this.username=userName;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Delete deleted;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    private List<RoleMaster> roleMaster;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_branch", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id") }
    )
    private List<Branch> branch;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Status enabled;

    //getter and setters

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "role_master")
public class RoleMaster {
    public RoleMaster() {
    }
    public RoleMaster(Integer id) {
        this.id=id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleMaster")
    private Set<UserMaster> userMaster;

  //getters and setters
}



@Entity
@Table(name="branch")
public class Branch {

    public Branch(){}
    public Branch(Integer branchId){
        this.branchId=branchId;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer branchId;
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Status status;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="branch")
    private List<UserMaster> userMaster;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Delete deleted;

//getters and setters
}

//Calling method
public List<Object> getUserNameByBranch(Integer branchId) {
        List<RoleMaster> roleMaster =new ArrayList<>();
        roleMaster.add(new RoleMaster(3));
        roleMaster.add(new RoleMaster(2));
        return userMasterRepository.getUserNameByBranch(branchId,roleMaster);
    }


@Query("select u.username from Branch b "
            + "join b.userMaster u "
            + "join u.roleMaster r "
            + "where b.branchId=:branchId "
            + "and (u.deleted is null or u.deleted=0) and u.roleMaster IN (:roleMaster)")
    List<Object> getUserNameByBranch(@Param("branchId") Integer branchId,@Param("roleMaster") List<RoleMaster> roleMaster);
```

```
Exception: Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [co.aaaid.passportmaker.bean.RoleMaster@60e0d16b] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [co.aaaid.passportmaker.bean.RoleMaster@60e0d16b] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
```

How to pass the roleMaster list parameter in order to get the result.